# How to build a seq2seq model for ASR, using mfcc vectors and corresponding word embedding vectors of the transcripts as the input and output data?

Tags: keras, speech-recognition, word-embedding, mfcc, attention-model

I am trying to build a voice to text model without using existing speech recognition libraries. I am using common-voice dataset from mozilla. I have done the data preprocessing where I extracted mfcc features from the input audio files and also used word embeddings to get vectors for the transcripts.

#### mfcc_X_train : mfcc vectors from audio files

```
array([[-2.59124781e+02,  1.13265526e+02,  1.30979551e+01, ...,
    -2.79187146e+00,  1.82840353e+00, -8.83761218e-01],
   [-4.37804550e+02,  1.09338910e+02,  1.27755069e+01, ...,
     2.80325980e-02, -3.02936100e+00, -4.85614372e+00],
   [-4.20299606e+02,  5.03662679e+01,  5.93071849e+00, ...,
     2.72814692e+00, -1.02385068e+01, -1.51062112e+00],
   ...,
   [-3.91306660e+02,  5.17953868e+01,  1.03543497e+01, ...,
    -4.19143153e+00, -8.23613404e+00, -6.86574230e+00],
   [-3.62376932e+02,  6.76604652e+01,  1.77715018e+01, ...,
    -8.71072342e-01, -4.66138009e+00, -4.56961645e+00],
   [-3.86323644e+02,  1.14792009e+02, -1.33781946e+01, ...,
    -1.60223182e-01, -7.69392168e+00, -3.41955318e+00]])
```

#### y_train : one hot representations of the embedding vectors

```
array([[[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   [[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    ...,
    [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

   ...,
```

I am stuck in building a seq2seq model for this. Can anyone help how to build a seq2seq model for this use case.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @NikolasRieble - I am not knowing how to build a seq2seq model for the input mfcc vectors and output embedding vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build model like this: [Neural machine translation with attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention). The mfcc vectors is like word embeding of encoder input. Set the input for fitting the model.